# The attribute rowspan causes the succeeding <tr> element to be displayed in the previous row in browser

Tags: html

I'm trying to get a single row to span down 9 rows, but for some reason the row that is supposed to display under the spanned row appears in the spanned row rather than below it. Any help is greatly appreciated! Here's the code:

```html
<table>
                <thead>
                <tr> 
                    <th scope="col"> GDP index </th> 
                    <th scope="col"> Vegas track </th>
                    <th scope="col"> Boston track </th> 
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <tr> 
                    <th scope="row"> Number one </th> 
                    <td> 1:32:33 </td>
                    <td> 2:32:69 </td>
                    
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="9" scope="row"> Number two - ten </th>
                    <td rowspan="9" colspan="2"> Did not compete </th>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"> Number eleven </th>
                    <td> 45:12:02 </td>
                    <td> 3:04:05 </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>

                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th> Total time </th>
                    <td> 10:48:22 </td>
                    <td> 11:43:44 </td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
    </table>
```

The row with the heading "Number eleven" is what is supposed to appear beneath the previous row but instead appears in the previous row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

`rowspan=9` means "This cell should appear in this row and the next 8 rows"

Since "Number eleven" is in *the next row*, it becomes the 4th cell in that row due to the earlier row having cells that use up the first three positions in the next row.

Here is a simpler example:

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope=col>Column 1</th>
    <th scope=col>Column 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1, Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 1, Col 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=3>Row 2-4, Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 2, Col 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3, Col 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 4, Col 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 5, Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 5, Col 2</td>
  </tr>
```

The **span** means it spans across rows, not that it **just** has the height of multiple rows.

If you don't want that behaviour, don't cause it with `rowspan`.

If your goal is to create a row which has the **height** of nine rows, but not actually have cells in it which span across nine rows: Use the CSS `height` property.

Comment: My goal is to start a new row immediately after the row that spans 9 rows. I do not want the next row to be a 4th cell. And yes I know about the height attribute, I was wondering if this could be done without that attribute

Comment: The <tr> element is supposed to denote the start of a new row. Why isn't it doing that here? Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the <tr> element?

Comment: @MatthewS. — I already explained that in the answer. `<tr>` does start a new row. The cell that spans multiple rows is in both those rows. That's what span means. You are misunderstanding `rowspan`, not `<tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `rowspan="9"`.  Once I did that, then the Number eleven row was placed under the Number two-ten row.

[image]

Here is another way to look at this example to see the behavior:

```
<table border="1">
                <thead>
                <tr> 
                    <th scope="col"> GDP index </th> 
                    <th scope="col"> Vegas track </th>
                    <th scope="col"> Boston track </th> 
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <tr> 
                    <th scope="row"> Number one </th> 
                    <td> 1:32:33 </td>
                    <td> 2:32:69 </td>
                    
                </tr>

                <tr style="background-color: yellow;">
                    <th rowspan="9" scope="row"> Number two - ten </th>
                    <td rowspan="9" colspan="2"> Did not compete </th>
                </tr>

                <tr><td></td></d></tr>
                <tr><td></td></d></tr>
                <tr><td></td></d></tr>
                <tr><td></td></d></tr>
                <tr><td></td></d></tr>
                <tr><td></td></d></tr>
                <tr><td></td></d></tr>
                <tr><td></td></d></tr>

                <tr style="background-color: orange;">
                    <th scope="row"> Number eleven </th>
                    <td> 45:12:02 </td>
                    <td> 3:04:05 </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>

                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th> Total time </th>
                    <td> 10:48:22 </td>
                    <td> 11:43:44 </td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
    </table>
```

[image]

Comment: I would like it to work with the rowspan attribute. This is an exercise for me in HTML, I don't care about functionality. If the <tr> element denotes the start of a new row, then why is my "Number eleven" heading displayed as a 4th column in the previous row?

Comment: If you want it to span down 9 rows, you need to have 9 existing rows in order to span down.  In your original code you do not.